# $k$ cells from any $k\times k$ subboard

Tags: combinatorics

> Cells in a $8\times 8$ board are colored black or white. What is the maximum number of numbers $1\leq k\leq 8$ such that for any $k\times k$ subboard, exactly $k$ cells are black.

If all cells in the board are black, then only $k=1$ works, giving $1$ number. If all cells are white, no number works.

If all cells in the $4$th row are black and the rest white, then $k=5,6,7,8$ works, giving $4$ numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say a board coloring has the $k$-subboard property, $k = 1, \ldots, 8$, if in any $k\times k$ subboard exactly $k$ cells are black.

Suppose we have two different $k, k'$ such that $k$ divides $k'$. If each $k\times k$-subboard has $k$ black cells, then each $k'\times k'$- subboard (consisting of $(k'/k)^2$ subboards of size $k\times k$) has $k\cdot(k'/k)^2$ black cells, and $k\cdot(k'/k)^2 > k'$, so no $k'\times k'$-subboard has $k'$ black cells. The board can therefore not satisfy the $k$-subboard property and the $k'$-subboard property at the same time.

We can partition $\{1, \ldots, 8\}$ into four subsets $\{1, 2, 4, 8\}, \{3, 6\}, \{5\}, \{7\}$ such that in every subset any element divides any other.

Hence, for any possible cell coloring, there can be at most $4$ different $k$ such that the board satisfies the $k$-subboard property, at most one from each of the four subsets.

And you've already shown that it works for $5, 6, 7, 8$, so the maximum number of numbers is $4$.